# How to correctly use LIKE in the code block of a Reclass expression in ModelBuilder Calculate Field

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator

I have a Reclass expression that works when i am search for single instance of a data field.

I also wish the Reclass to work with a SQL type LIKE selection with Wildcards. e.g. I need to reclassify any example where the field include the text 'Inland Water' but i do not know what text may precede or follow this text term.

I have tried the following but it does not work. I get a syntax error.

```py
Expression
Reclass(!DescGroup!)

Code Block
def Reclass (DescGroup):
  if (DescGroup == 'Sea') :
    return 'K'
  elif (DescGroup LIKE '%Inland water%') :
    return 'G'
```

Any thoughts, tips or help would be very useful.

Thanks.

[image: error message]

Comment: You need a colon at the end of your elif statement.

Comment: thank you, yes i have corrected that. the ommission error was just in the text here on the web,not in the code i tested in arcgis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the help on [SQL expressions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000033000000), it says

> Caution: SQL syntax does not work for calculating fields using Field
>   Calculator.

To emulate SQL's `LIKE` you should be able use the `in` operator, like so:

```py
"hi" in "isn'tthiscool"
>>>True

"hit" in "isn'tthiscool"
>>>False
```

So, your code now becomes:

```py
def Reclass (DescGroup):
  if (DescGroup == 'Sea') :
    return 'K'
  elif ('Inland water' in DescGroup) :
    return 'G'
  else:
    return 'NA'
```

You might need to change the string that is being checked by `in` as needed. I've added an else statement as the field calculator will fail if neither of the two first statements are true.

Comment: That works great, thanks! I had thought the issue was the LIKE command but I could not find any alternative information in ArcGIS or on Python websites. cheers, Jonathan